# How to add param values to radio button tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a subscription form. And I moved all the information to one page. Previously I link users to two separate pages for the plans `/subscriptions/new?plan_id=1` or `/subscriptions/new?plan_id=12`.

Now the page is only `subscriptions/new`. How can I add the params to each radio value so that when the user checks out with their credit card or paypal that it will sign them up for the subscription plan they selected with the radio button?

```
  <%= form_for @subscription do |f| %>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="plan">
      <%= image_tag "/assets/best1.png" %>

      <h1><%= radio_button_tag :plan_id, '1,', true %><label for="plan_id_1"><span><span></span></span></label>$13.50 a year</h1>
      <h2>12-Month Membership</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="plan">
      <h1><%= radio_button_tag :plan_id, '2' %><label for="plan_id_2"><span><span></span></span></label>$1.35 a month</h1>
      <h2>1-Month Membership</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sm_form_container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="field">
        <h1>Payment Information</h1>
     </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="field">

      <% if @subscription.errors.any? %>

          <h2><%= pluralize(@subscription.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this subscription from being saved:</h2>
          <ul>
          <% @subscription.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>

      <% end %>

      <%= f.hidden_field :plan_id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :paypal_customer_token %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :paypal_payment_token %>

      <% unless @subscription.payment_provided? %>

        <%= radio_button_tag :pay_with, :card, true %>
        <%= label_tag :pay_with_card do %>
          <%= image_tag "visa.png" %>
          <%= image_tag "mastercard.png" %>
          <%= image_tag "discover.png" %>
          <%= image_tag "american_express.png" %>
          <%= image_tag "jcb.png" %>
        <% end %>
        <%= radio_button_tag :pay_with, :paypal %>
        <%= label_tag :pay_with_paypal do %>
          <%= image_tag "paypal.png" %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="paypal_checkout" style="display:none">
        <%= link_to image_tag("https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif"), paypal_checkout_path(plan_id: @subscription.plan_id) %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="billing_fields">
      <div class="field">
          <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %> 
          <%= f.hidden_field :email, :value => current_user.email  %>
        </div>
        <% if @subscription.payment_provided? %>
          Payment has been provided. Click "Subscribe" to complete the subscription.
        <% else %>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="field">
            <%= label_tag :card_owner, "Name (as it appears on the card)" %>
            <%= text_field_tag :card_owner, nil, name: nil %>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
            <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="field">
            <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %>
            <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>
          </div>
          <div class="field" id="expiration">
            <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %><br />
            <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
            <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
        <div id="stripe_error">
          <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="field"><%= f.submit "Subscribe", class: 'btn', style: "width: 40%; margin-left: 165px"  %></div>
      </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Subscriptions controller:

```
      def new
        plan = Plan.find(1)
        @subscription = plan.subscriptions.build
        if params[:PayerID]
          @subscription.paypal_customer_token = params[:PayerID]
          @subscription.paypal_payment_token = params[:token]
          @subscription.email = @subscription.paypal.checkout_details.email
        end
        render layout: 'new_application'   end

 def paypal_checkout
    plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    subscription = plan.subscriptions.build
    redirect_to subscription.paypal.checkout_url(
      return_url: new_subscription_url(:plan_id => plan.id),
      cancel_url: root_url
    )
  end
```

Routes:

```
  resources :subscriptions
  resources :plans
  get 'paypal/checkout', to: 'subscriptions#paypal_checkout'
```

Comment: is there a reason why you use the `*_tag` helpers? If `@subscription` is a model instance, you could just do `<%= f.radio_button :plan_id, 1 %>` and `<%= f.radio_button :plan_id, 2 %>` respectively and get the selected value with `params[:subscription][:plan_id]`

Comment: @sled I just included the controller. I forgot that I had it reading `plan = Plan.find(1)` which is why it would always take you to plan 1. I was thinking of changing the controller to `plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])` which should work if I pass in views. Can you show example of passing the params in the view however?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a Membership model, and a Membership has an id and a name (among other things). Subscription has a plan_id (the membership plan).

The subscription controller loads the memberships from the DB.

```
def edit
  @memberships = Memberships.all
end
```

And in the edit view, you use the memberships to populate the set of radio buttons, setting the plan_id to the membership id (I use haml, and this is from a table layout, but it should translate easy enough)

```
%td
  - @memberships.each do |membership|
    = f.radio_button(:plan_id, membership.id)
    = f.label :plan_id, membership.name
    %br
```

When you save, the subscription model built from params will have a plan_id value of the selected membership model.

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-fill the model in your `new` action and then use the form builder, so that these pre-filled values propagate to the view.

**Controller:**

```
def new
  if params.has_key?(:plan_id) 
    plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
  else
    # make plan with id 1 our default plan if no plan_id has been given
    plan = Plan.find(1)
  end

  # this should set the plan_id in the Subscription model,
  # if not - ensure you have a `belongs_to :plan` inside your Subscription model.
  @subscription = plan.subscriptions.build
  if params[:PayerID]
    @subscription.paypal_customer_token = params[:PayerID]
    @subscription.paypal_payment_token = params[:token]
    @subscription.email = @subscription.paypal.checkout_details.email
  end
  render layout: 'new_application'   
end
```

**View:**

Remove the hidden field tag `<%= f.hidden_field :plan_id %>` first, then adapt this part to use the form builder, i.e `<%= f.radio_button :plan_id, ... %>`. The form builder will then take care of selecting the right radio button.

```
  <%= form_for @subscription do |f| %>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="plan">
      <%= image_tag "/assets/best1.png" %>

      <h1><%= f.radio_button :plan_id, 1 %><label for="plan_id_1"><span><span></span></span></label>$13.50 a year</h1>
      <h2>12-Month Membership</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="plan">
      <h1><%= f.radio_button :plan_id, 2 %><label for="plan_id_2"><span><span></span></span></label>$1.35 a month</h1>
      <h2>1-Month Membership</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  ....
```

Comment: I just took a quick look at your code. I don't see anything different that you did. By saying that I mean before I made that last post I did those settle changes before to no success. I was running into `Couldn't find Plan without an ID` which is why I ask how would I pass params in the views. I will c&p your code, but it's literally the same thing I tried in the past.

Comment: To confirm it reproduce the same error (as we had the same code). `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /subscriptions/new
 Couldn't find Plan without an ID` on line `plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])`

Comment: which simply means you are not passing a plan_id paramter in the url, how does your route look like? I added a check which takes the product with `ID=1` when no plan id has been passed.

Comment: Ah I forgot the other code in subscriptions controller. The `paypal_checkout` action which gets called on. Code added

Comment: mhh... in your browser when you get redirected to the `new` controller is there a parameter in the url, e.g '/subscriptions/new?plan_id=2` or the like?

Comment: how is the application flow? user comes to `new`, then selects a plan, submits the form - gets to the `create` method and then goes to `paypal_checkout` and comes back to `new` again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69495/discussion-between-sled-and-cornelius-wilson).

Comment: It's all on one page. So users goes to new, select the plan, clicks the paypal button (or fills out stripe credit card form), user is taken to paypal, redirected to subscription plan page (shows information on their subscription)